# Continuous Linear Mapping $C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$

Tags: operator-theory, continuity

Show that $L(f)(x)= \int_0^x f(t) dt $ is a continuous linear mapping from $C[0,1]$ into itself.

Do I only have to show that the operator is bounded? How to do I explicitly choose my $M$ such that $\|L \ f\|<M\|f\|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, continuous is equivalent to bounded, among linear mappings between normed spaces.

Choose $M$ to be the length of the given interval, now $M=1$ will do it.

> $\left| \displaystyle\int_0^x f(t)\,dt\right| \ \le \ \int_0^x|f(t)|\,dt\ \le \ \int_0^1|f(t)|\,dt\  \le\ \int_0^1\,\|f\|_\max = 1\cdot \|f\|_\max$

Comment: @Berci Is M=1=1-0 from C[0,1]?

Comment: Yes. The length of the interval.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is continuous, then $F=\displaystyle\int_0^x f$ is differentiable, thus clearly continuous.

On the other hand, suppose that $$\lVert f-g\rVert_\infty<\frac{\epsilon}2$$

Then for $0\leq x \leq 1$,$$\left|\int_0^x(f-g)\right|\leq \int_0^x|f-g|\leq\int_0^1 \lVert f-g\rVert_\infty<1\cdot\frac{\epsilon}2=\frac{\epsilon}2$$

which means $$\lVert F-G\rVert_\infty\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$$